# How to I fix a unexpected string output 'null' in toString

Tags: java, tostring

I'm working on my first assignment with one class referencing another class, I'm afraid I missed something crucial and when I run the test class, the string variable 'direction' returns null

I've tried changing the accessors, method types, and reworking the code but none of them seem to be working

```
public class Bug
{
    private int position;
    private boolean directionRight;
    private String direction; 
    public String result;

    //setting starting position for bug
    public Bug()
    {
        position = 0;
        directionRight = true;
    }

    //move the bug one increment 
    public int Move()
    {
       if (directionRight == true) 
         {
          ++position;
        }
       else
       {
         --position;  
        }

       return position;
        }

    //change direction of bug
    public Boolean Turn()
    {
      this.directionRight = !this.directionRight;

      return directionRight;
        }

    //returns direction of bug in form of a string    
    public String Direction()
    {
        if (directionRight == true) {
            String direction = "right";
        }
        else {
            String direction = "left";
        }
        return direction;
    }

    //string with direction and position of the bug
    public String toString()
    {
        String result = "the direction is: " + direction + " the position is: " + position;
        return result;
    }
}


---

public class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
       Bug Worm = new Bug();
       //direction = right, position = 3
       Worm.Move() ;
       Worm.Move() ;
       Worm.Move() ;
       Worm.Move() ;
       Worm.Move() ;
       Worm.Turn() ; 
       Worm.Move() ;
       Worm.Move() ;
       Worm.Move() ;
       Worm.Turn() ; 
       Worm.Move() ;

       System.out.println(Worm.toString());
    }
}
```

I expect the test to return 
the direction is: right the position is: 3

Instead, I get 
the direction is: null the position is: 3

Comment: You are not utilizing your object `Bug` completely. You never call the function `Direction()` to change the value of  `direction` so the result remain to `null`
EDIT: and even you call the `Direction()` you are just creating new variable `direction` and not assigning value to `this.direction`

Comment: One remark on the code: in Java, methods should start with a lowercase letter (`Direction()` -> `direction()`, `Turn()` -> `turn()`).

Comment: @Turing85 I edit my comment, sorry about that

Comment: Obs: it is Java convention to name methods starting with lower case letters (classes start with upper case)... and `if (directionRight == true)` is an unnecessary comparison, if already tests for true; so `if (directionRight)` is doing the same... there is also a difference between the primitive type `boolean` and the class `Boolean`

Comment: more: you are initializing `directionRight = true` in constructor, why not `direction`? Actually, IMO, there is no need for the `direction` field at all, it is more a possibility for bugs (getting wrong inconsistent value, like forgetting to update it after changing `directionRight`).... also the `result` field is not initialized and never used

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are never calling the `Direction()` method which is the one that assigns a non-null value to `direction`. But you must remove `String direction =` and replace it with `this.direction =`. This way, you refer to the member variable, and not a localized string that you create.

Comment: The method does assign a value to the two block-scoped variables `direction`, but not to the property `direction`. It does return the property `direction`, which (still) is `null`.

Comment: Nope Chirs is correct, he never callsthe `Direction()`

Comment: @Francisaskquestion I never said that OP does call the method. But calling the method makes no difference, since the method is broken aswell.

Comment: ahh yes, sorry about that, but generally if the method `Direction()` is correct, nevertheless he never use it. 
So the `String direction` must be change to `this.direction`

Comment: Yeah, I see what you mean. The use of ```String``` before the variable name denotes it as a local instance of ```direction```.

Comment: @chris-turgeon I tried changing it from direction to Direction() in my toString, but it made no difference

Comment: @DaleO'Connell Have you changed your two uses of ```String direction =``` to ```this.direction =```. The keyword ```this``` refers to the member variable of your class, which is the one you are trying to assign a value to.

Comment: changing it to 'this.direction' worked, thank you both!! @Francis-ask-question

Comment: @DaleO'Connell no need to use `this`, just `direction =` (instead of creating new local variable `String direction`)

Answer (score 2):

You aren't calling or setting the `direction`. This should fix it.

```
public String Direction()
    {
        if (directionRight == true) {
            direction = "right";
        }
        else {
            direction = "left";
        }
        return direction;
    }
public String toString()
{
    String result = "the direction is: " + Direction() + " the position is: " + position;
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help! I changed it to String result = "the direction is: " + Direction() + " the position is: " + position; but I'm still getting null in the test run

Comment: @DaleO'Connell you never call the method `Direction()`

Comment: @Francisaskquestion how not? what is `...+ Direction() + ...` in his comment? he probably missed to change the method itself (remove declaration of variable)